# Bundling and Minification with .net loses image references within CSS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I realize this has been asked through out the web, but i cant seem to find a definitive answers on how to resolve this issue.

this is how we are bundling

```
// iPortal Specific 
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/MyCSS")
            .Include("~/Content/css/MyCSS.css")
            .Include("~/Content/css/MyCSSMedia.css"));
```

and then within _layouts pages:-

```
  @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css/MyCSS")
```

where "~bundles/css/MyCSS" is a virtual directory, in that it doesnt exist on the server.

Our structure for the CSS is :-

```
Content
   CSS
      MyCSS.css
      _Images
```

where MyCSS.css references images within "_images" folder

We have tried using

```
.Include("~/Content/css/MyCSS.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
```

which didn't work.

and also tried

```
 public class CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper : IItemTransform
{
    public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
    {
        return new CssRewriteUrlTransform().Process("~" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(includedVirtualPath), input);
    }
}
```

again, which didn't work.

The only other solution that we have found is to alter the virtual directories to match the physical directories,  which doesn't really feel right,

Are we missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you extract the resulting css file in the html, it looks like this:

> bundles/css

While the images are in:

> Content/Images

The CSS points to `bundles/_Images`, which obviously doesn't exist.

You have two options I think:

1. Move the images to the top level, so your CSS can point there (this will both work bundled or not)
2. Replace the path of the images in the CSS in your `CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper` to `../Content/_Images`

Comment: thank you, this would work for this particular file, however, we are also using bootstrap and font awesome, with which we are experiencing the same issue (due to the fact as you mention its looking at bundles/xxxx for anything that embedded)